# Adobe Edge Animate Bootstrapping with javascript on screen resize

Tags: animation, adobe-edge

I’m using Adobe Edge Animate and I am hoping to call sym.playReverse(); or sym.play(1000); on sym.$(“sam”) on a screen resize by bootstrapping with javascript. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion in your question. You want to call sym.playReverse() on a symbol which is the stage? Or is it the symbol "sam" inside the stage?

Let's assume you want to call playReverse() on a symbol named "sam" inside the stage.

Suppose your composition name is EDGE-12345678.
Javascript code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    // Replace with your composition name. You read it in the proerties of the Stage.
    var composition = AdobeEdge.getComposition("EDGE-12345678");
    var stage = composition.getStage();
    // Get the sam symbol, child of stage.
    var symbolSam = stage.getSymbol("sam");
    symbolSam.playReverse();
});
```